# where to put ticket for missing os and release

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can a support ticket be filed for a missing os and release.
I am porting groovy to the Raspberry PI and the Raspbain os (arm6hf)
Fuerte already works on this platform with a few lies (ie. ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=debian:squeeze).  I have used the same override but I still find
that rosdep is missing a lot of libraries that have been loaded including
rospkg.
If you can point me to the files I can supply the changes for the code to support this.

Partial Answer -
After searching for the rosdep documentation I found the ros.org/wiki/rosdep docs
and took the rosdep documentation link to ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/
which lists the current os's for fuerte.  On that page is listed the developers guide
link.  In that page there is the hint that the program called is rospkg.os_detect.
I then went to the master library (Internet) and asked the head librarian (google) what was rospkg.os_detect and the first answer given was from upenn.edu.  I went there and that page has information on OS Detection.  It also supplied a test command line that allowed me to start finding the software programs.
python -m rospkg.os_detect
From that I was able to change down the filesystem tree and find rospkg/os_detect.py
Now I have a place to start the necessary mods for adding a new system/release.

I have just found on my machine the initial info for what to change:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg
inside this is the os_detect.py script.
It appears that code changes have to be made to identify the os and release here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51391/where-to-put-ticket-for-missing-os-and-release/) by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All package wiki pages should have a link at the bottom to open tickets. [rosdep has one](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep)

And I think that there's a [related ticket](https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/51) already.

For adding support for a new OS the [developers guide](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/developers_guide.html) has instructions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1